# The difference between operator condition, differential condition and algebraic condition?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, terminology, definition, mathematics

It is well known that the gauge potential $A_\mu=(\phi,-\vec{A})$ has gauge symmetry and one could impose Lorenz and Coulomb gauge simultaneously to it to eliminate redundant degrees of freedom. In particular, the Lorenz Gauge is a partial gauge fixing which requires $\partial^\mu A_\mu=0$. However, it was recently revealed to me that the so called operator condition $G=\partial^\mu A_\mu$ is such that $G\neq 0$ for the following reasons:

\begin{align}
[\partial^\mu A_\mu(x), A_\nu(y)]=-i\partial^\nu D(x-y)\neq 0
\end{align}
where $$D(x)\equiv -i\int\frac{d^3\vec k}{2\omega_k (2\pi)^3}(e^{-ikx}-e^{ikx})$$
Could someone please explain to me what exactly is operator condition and what is the difference between it and the Lorenz Gauge, and in particular how to resolve this apparent contradiction?

Answer (score -1):

Gauge freedom means that the field describing the physics has more degrees of freedoms that actually involved in the dynamics. In case of Electrodynamics one wants to establish a Lorentz-invariant theory and therefore the use of a 4-vector potential is unavoidable. However, the 4-vector potential has 4 components whereas in the free Maxwell equation only 2 degrees of freedoms are necessary to describe the dynamics. So there are 2 superfluous degrees of freedom.
So an additional condition is imposed to fix the superfluous degrees of freedom which called gauge fixing. But the gauge fixing is a priori a free condition, so it could be  $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} =0$ or $\partial^\mu A_{\mu}=0$ or even  $\partial^\mu A_{\mu}=G\neq 0$.
Usually, a condition is chosen which is convenient for the problem, i.e. that the equations which yield after the gauge fixing are simple, respectively easy to solve.

In relativistic Quantum Field Theory one is inclined to use a Lorentz-covariant gauge fixing in order to maintain a manifest Lorentz-covariant formalism, however, we could actually also use a gauge-fixing condition which is not Lorentz-covariant which can be okay for a certain purpose. In the meantime many different gauge conditions for the electromagnetic field have been used which can be useful for a certain problem to be solved. The obtained equations for the 4-vector potential and their solution will depend on the gauge fixing, but once the field strengths are computed, this dependence will disappear.

So as the word gauge freedom suggests, we are free to choose a gauge condition, so it can be  $\partial^\mu A_{\mu}=0 $ or $ \partial^\mu A_{\mu}\neq 0$, but once chosen we have to stick to it in the subsequent calculation.  (As far as I know
$ \partial^\mu A_{\mu}=G\neq 0$ is for instance used for calculation of the Lorentz-covariant photon propagator in the path integral formalism).

So there is no contradiction as just explained. On the other I wonder if it were possible to apply Coulomb-gauge and Lorenz-gauge simultaneously.

Also incomplete gauge fixing exists, i.e. a certain gauge fixing condition does not completely fix the 2 superfluous degrees of freedom. In that case more  gauge fixing conditions are necessary.
This might even the case for
$\partial^\mu A_{\mu}=0 $ or $\partial^\mu A_{\mu}=G\neq 0 $ But, of course, an additional gauge fixing condition should be compatible with the first gauge fixing condition. So one would never require $\partial^\mu A_{\mu}=0 $ and $\partial^\mu A_{\mu}=G\neq 0 $ at a time.